# Display live camera feed with object recognition markers Python ImageAI OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, imageai

I've been using the image AI library to create a simple object detection system using python, which currently records video using the webcam and as far as I can tell detects objects live, once the program stops, a video file is created with object markers overlayed on the video. The working code:

```
from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
import os
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

current_directory = os.getcwd()

detector = VideoObjectDetection()

detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()

detector.setModelPath(r"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\image\yolo.h5")
detector.loadModel()

detections = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(
camera_input=camera,
output_file_path = r"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\image\footage_detected", frames_per_second=20, log_progress=True)

for eachObject in detections:
    print(
         eachObject["name"] , " : ",
         eachObject["percentage_probability"], " : ",
         eachObject["box_points"] )
    print("--------------------------------")
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like the program to display each frame on the display as it is being recorded *with* the object markers overlayed on the live feed as it detects them. I am only able to get the live camera feed directly from opencv without the object markers.

I attempted to use opencv and imageai to take each frame, use the `detectObjectsFromImage` method to process each frame and then using the output of the method with the opencv `imshow` method. However it gives the error:

> ValueError: "Ensure you specified correct input image, input type,
> output type and/or output image path"

Here is the code where I attempt to do this:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os
import cv2

current_directory = os.getcwd()

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


detector = ObjectDetection()

detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()

detector.setModelPath(r"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\image\yolo.h5")
detector.loadModel()
while True:
    ret, frame = camera.read()

    returned_image, detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(
    input_image = (frame),
    output_type = "array"
    )
    for eachObject in detections:
        print(
             eachObject["name"] , " : ",
             eachObject["percentage_probability"], " : ",
             eachObject["box_points"] )
        print("--------------------------------")

    cv2.imshow('frame', returned_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Please let if this is possible, and if so how can it be done using the ImageAI library?
Thank you in advance.

Edit: here is the complete traceback.

```txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luca\anaconda3\envs\objectreconition\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\__init__.py", line 285, in detectObjectsFromImage
    input_image = cv2.imread(input_image)
TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\image\main 2.py", line 22, in <module>
    output_type = "array"
  File "C:\Users\Luca\anaconda3\envs\objectreconition\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\__init__.py", line 392, in detectObjectsFromImage
    "Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output image path ")
ValueError: Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output image path
```

Comment: complete traceback please. -- and where's the error checking that is needed when using VideoCapture? don't follow tutorials that don't show this properly

Comment: sorry could you please clarify - would you like me to post the whole error?

Comment: yes always the complete traceback. [edit] your question to add it. -- next you'll have to debug your code, i.e. figure out what values are in your variables, vs. what you *think* is in there.

Comment: @jerico The error occurs when you initiate `detectObjectsFromImage()`. `input_image` has to be an image file not an array `frame`. That's why the error "Ensure you specified correct input image, input type, ...."

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detection/index.html) you cannot pass an array as input, only an image file

Comment: is there a way to somehow use it as an input?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've added full trackback

Comment: @jerico On [this page](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/video/index.html) there is a snippet that would show detected images once per second

Comment: your `imread` is wrong. you passed something other than a string. or rather, you use imageai in some way it's not designed for. it expects `input_image` to be a path. imageai documentation (very sparse!) indicates that you need to set `input_type`. their api design and documentation is awful. -- imageAI hasn't received any development for over a year. perhaps it's dead... it doesn't have many stars and forks on github either, so it seems to be unpopular. perhaps you might want to look for some other library.